# HTTP/SSH request not passing through some iptables rules

Tags: networking, ssh, apache2, iptables, firewall

I have an assignment to do using iptables to create a set of rules. 
Using marionnet, we simulate the following network:

[image: network diagram]

What we want here is to avoid "intrus" from being able to interact with the LAN the network on which "intrus" is connected is on the interface eth2 and we imagine that any other interface is a LAN we want to prevent "intrus" from interacting with. I've spent hours trying to figure out why my set of rules don't to what we want and trying different orders or methods but nothing worked out, so I suppose I'm misunderstanding something.
m1 and "intrus" have an apache server running and m2 have ssh running

The 4 behaviors we want to implement with rules are the following:

1. `intrus` can't access the private networks
2. any computer from one of the private networks connected to `routeur` can access `intrus`'s  web server
3. all request to `intrus` will be camouflaged as coming from `routeur`
4. `intrus` can be a client to m1's apache server and m2's ssh but while thinking that `routeur` is the host of those services meaning that `routeur` is his only service provider.

Here are my rules in the order I append them :

1. `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -m state --state NEW,RELATED -j DROP`
2. `iptables -A FORWARD -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,RELATED -j ACCEPT`
3. `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j SNAT --to 145.12.0.53`
4. This group:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
   ```

If I remember correctly, the order is like a pile, first come last served, which is why rule (1) is first.
With this set, the LAN can access `intrus`'s apache server but `intrus` can't access the services from the LAN when calling them through `routeur`.
If I change the first rule to a simple `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j DROP`
then m1 can't access `intrus`'s web server, and I don't even understand how the two versions are so different.
My guess is that those returning signals aren't collected by any of the rules and are destroyed by the first rule, but I don't get why.

So, after many hours searching alone, I'm asking for your help and anyone that may at least explain me something that it looks like I didn't get right have my thanks in advance

Comment: If your default policies are `ACCEPT` you don't need any `FORWARD` rules at all. However, consider a default policy of `DROP`, at least for your `FORWARD` chain. Your rule 1 is breaking things. You do not need your two `MASQUERADE` lines because they are covered by your rule 3. Learn and understand the differences between the `NEW`, `ESTABLISHED`, and `RELATED` states.

Comment: Ok, I guessed the two MASQUERADE lines weren't needed, but my teacher advised me to put those. I've read about the states, and now I get how the established state can help the message passing through, but if it's dropped it shouldn't allow m1 to intrus's http request then, so why this difference ?

Comment: Furthermore, the order look right so rule 1 should only intercept requests that are from eth2 and not an http/ssh request to routeur. Except if I completely reversed the order, but I don't think I did

Comment: Yes, you have the order of things backwards, it is first entered, first served. I don't understand what you are asking with the other comment.

Comment: I don't understand why dropping incoming requests from eth2 with states NEW and ESTABLISHED doesn't stop http request from m1 to intrus while a DROP without state does, because since NEW and ESTABLISHED are supposed to be blocked, replies to the http request should be blocked too. If I recall correctly, I even tried with NEW, ESTABLISHED and RELATED and still got the same result.

I'm gonna try with the reverse order as soon as I can, it may certainly be the source of my problems. Thanks for your help @DougSmythies

Comment: For debugging and understanding, make use of `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L` and tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer).